# Disable text wrap in asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The output is like this:

```
MyNameIsJohnSmithAnd
Imaperson
```

What I want is to display it in only one line

```
MyNameIsJohnSmithAndImaperson
```

My Aspx gridview code is:

```aspx
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
    BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="5" Font-Names="Calibri" 
    Font-Size="Medium" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="Black">
    <RowStyle Wrap="False"/>
    <EmptyDataRowStyle Wrap="False"/>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Wrap="False"/>
    <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" Wrap="False"/>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" Wrap="False"/>
    <EditRowStyle Wrap="False"/>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" Wrap="False"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

I disabled all the wrap property to false in gridview. but the text still wraps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try adding this event to your gridview.

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "white-space: nowrap;");
    }
}
```

[Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1104548.aspx/1) is the reference.

Comment: I tried many ways to do it directly in the .aspx file by setting attributes and styles, but this is the approach that finally worked

Comment: I added a `text-no-wrap` class to my CSS file and referenced it when defining my controls containing the text in my .aspx file.  For example: `<asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" class="text-no-wrap" Text='<%# Bind("Category") %>' />`

Answer (score 22):

You have to set the gridview's individual column's word wrap to False as well.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" >
            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
            </asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 3):

Very simple in .Net  Select your grid view (as in Design mode) in property window and follow this
 RowStyle -->Font -->>Wrap=False

Thats done

Comment: to add this in 'source' view.  Add :      RowStyle-Wrap="false"      into the gridview.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by css.

```
#GridView1
    {
      white-space:nowrap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My column header text was wrapping so I ended up needing a slightly different solution but similar to what user3578419 suggested.

In design view, I edited the 'ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle' property and changed the 'WrapMode' value to 'False'.

Comment: To expand on this solution, Switch to Design View, right click on the gridview, choose properties, expand HeaderStyle, and set the Wrap there to false. This adds the line                         <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" /> right after the </Columns> tag.